# Как сделать динамическую подстановку одного изображения в другое?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Всем привет. Референс: http://albico.ru/products/konstruktor/ . Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом реализован конструктор, какими инструментами пользоваться, куда копать? На одном из форумов нашел совет воспользоваться ImageMagick, но я не нашел в нем того, что нужно.

Comment: Html + css + js и отправка ответа на сервер - вполне достаточно для такого конструктора... На самом деле, если возникают вопросы подобные то лучше воспользоваться услугами фрилансеров.

Comment: Там огромное кол-во табов (вкладок) с уже заранее готовыми рендерами.

Comment: Да, там просто 100500 картинок готовых.